# Not able to set cache-control header for my static resources Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, static

I am using Express in the backend and React(create-react-app) in the frontend. 
React produces all my bundled assets in `client/build/static` directory

The directory has three folders in it `css`, `js`, `media`. I see that they have a max-age=0 in the network tab of the developer console.

So, I try to use express static middleware to set Cache-Control headers for these folders by writing the following code in my app.js file which is inside `server` directory

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", 
    "client/build/static"), {
       maxage: 31536000
}))
```

But it does not seem to have any effect. Does anyone know how to set Cache-Control to folders in express

EDIT:- by following @Giovanny's answer, I made the rectifications but still I have max-age=0 set for the headers

[image: request headers]

I think it is because of the default setting of request headers by the client?

[image: request headers]

Answer (score 5):

Your code looks right, the only thing is you are setting the option `maxage` instead of `maxAge`. This works as expected:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", 
    "client/build/static"), {
       maxAge: 31536000
}))
```

You can see the list of options for static files here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

You can specify in this other way the cache control header and it will cache accordingly. The idea would be to add a call to res.set() prior to any output.

```
res.set('Cache-Control', 'client/build/static, max-age=31557600');
```

Comment: I saw `maxage` being used in some blog. my bad.

Comment: I have tried setting maxAge as well but still does not seem to work. maxage is also a valid key by the way.